# How to retrieve data on button and move to Next button?

Tags: java, android, database, android-layout

I am working on an Android quiz . I have created my database with one question and four options along-with difficulty level. I have created a layout to display the question with four buttons . Now the problem is how will i connect my database with the question and four buttons.

so as to, when I click on right button it moves to the next question and when I click on wrong button it gives an error and exits.

Code In XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="110dp" 
    android:paddingTop="5dip" android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#99CCFF"
        android:id="@+id/group1">

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:background="#0000CC"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/question"/>

        <Button android:onClick="false" android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_width="150dip" />

        <Button android:onClick="false" android:id="@+id/answer2"
            android:layout_width="150dip" />    
        <Button android:onClick="false" android:id="@+id/answer3" 
            android:layout_width="150dip"/> 
        <Button android:onClick="false" android:id="@+id/answer4"
            android:layout_width="150dip" />    
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

MY DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.starchazer.cyk/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "questionsDb";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!dbExist)
    {
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.




public List<Question> getQuestionSet(int difficulty, int numQ){
    List<Question> questionSet = new ArrayList<Question>();
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE DIFFICULTY=" + difficulty +
            " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + numQ, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()){
        //Log.d("QUESTION", "Question Found in DB: " + c.getString(1));
        Question q = new Question();
        q.setQuestion(c.getString(1));
        q.setAnswer(c.getString(2));
        q.setOption1(c.getString(3));
        q.setOption2(c.getString(4));
        q.setOption3(c.getString(5));
        q.setRating(difficulty);
        questionSet.add(q);
    }
    return questionSet;
}
}
```

MY QuestionActivity

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Question currentQ;
private GamePlay currentGame;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);
    /**
     * Configure current game and get question
     */



    currentGame = ((XYZ_Application)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
    currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
    Button c1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1 );
    c1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button c2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2 );
    c2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button c3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3 );
    c3.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button c4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4 );
    c4.setOnClickListener(this);

    /**
     * Update the question and answer options..
     */
    setQuestions();

}


/**
 * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
 * current question
 */
private void setQuestions() {
    //set the question text from current question
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    //set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

    TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

    TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

    TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {


    /**
     * validate a buttonselected has been selected
     */    
    if (!checkAnswer()) return;


    /**
     * check if end of game
     */
    if (currentGame.isGameOver()){


        Intent i = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


/**
 * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
 * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
 */
private boolean checkAnswer() {
    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
    if (answer==null){

        return false;
    }
    else {

        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
        }
        else{
            //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
        }
        return true;
    }
}


/**
 * 
 */
private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    Button c1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    Button c2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    Button c3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    Button c4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    if (c1.callOnClick())
    {
        return c1.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c2.callOnClick())
    {
        return c2.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c3.callOnClick())
    {
        return c3.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c4.callOnClick())
    {
        return c4.getText().toString();
    }

    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: I just changed in my QuestionActivty removed `if(!CheckedAnswer()) return;`
then my Data Is coming from the database and my question changed As well. But i am not able to Check My answer is right or wrong it just moving to another question without checking my button. Can Anyone help me how to check my right answer.In Above QuestionActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry I will not be giving code here.

Here is what I would have done
When Actvity Starts

1. Load Question from Db with Options
2. I ll prefer option as array/arraylist
3. Assign Text Option to each button
4. Add a common onclick listener like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10586)

   ```
   public void onClick(View v){
   int id=v.getId();
   String answer=v.getText();
   if(answer.equals('ANSWER FROM DB'){
   // If right then next question
   // Else to MainActivity
       }

   /**switch(id){
       case R.id.answer1:
            processAnswer(1);

            break;
       case R.id.answer2:
            processAnswer(2);
            break;
       // So on
       }
    **/
   }
   ```

And processAnswer would look like

```
void processAnswer(int option){
// Since I have the option here
// I will check it with Database
// If its correct then next question else exit
}
```

Comment: ok...i have implemented it but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: check updated answer, in your onclick you can directly get the text on view. You may need to cast it to button

Comment: still i am unable to retrieve data from this method .