# How to check Correct Data Coming from Database

Tags: java, android, database

I wanted to check correct answer from database onClick button. I have retrieved Data From Database [a link][How to retrieve data on button and move to Next button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485192/how-to-retrieve-data-on-button-and-move-to-next-button), but I am not able to check whether my answer is right or wrong.  So can any one help me what function I used so it check my right data from database. I have implemented it like this:-

```
private boolean checkAnswer() {
    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
    if (answer==null){

        return false;
    }
    else {

        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {

            currentGame.incrementScore();
        }
        else{

            currentGame.decrementScore();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

but it can't work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data on button and move to Next button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485192/how-to-retrieve-data-on-button-and-move-to-next-button)

Comment: Sorry ! I Just want to add this question as a link here for explaining the detail of this Question.

Comment: @Avadhani can u help me how to put a link question to ask new question.